# Select checked items from an array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays. One for data and one which contains `1` for each item which I want to select from an array and `0` for each item which I want to ignore.

```
data = [1 2 3 4 5];
list = [1 0 1 0 1];
```

Is there a quick one-liner way to get checked elements (1, 3 and 5) from the data array without doing something like:

```
newdata = [];
for i=1:numel(data)
    if list(i) == 1
        newdata(end+1) = data(i);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it directly:

```
data(list == 1)
```

or

```
data(logical(list))
```